# How to reduce space between specific cells and properly center caption table?

Tags: tables, spacing, margins, cell

I've just recently started to use LaTeX and It's been wonderful. However, I've been struggling with tables in general.

This is by far my best table creation but still isn't perfect. As you can see caption's table is not properly center and "Constant current" from Tektronix and Maynuo's column have too much space between cells.

[image]

Here's my code, I'll put all packages in case there's something wrong there.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url, graphicx}

\usepackage[center]{caption}

\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{gensymb}    
\usepackage{enumitem}   

\raggedbottom       

\usepackage{helvet}                 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}       

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}               
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}    

\usepackage[notlot,notlof,nottoc,notindex]{tocbibind}   
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}

\usepackage{array}      
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{booktabs}       
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\usepackage{changepage} 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5cm}{}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\footnotesize
\begin{center}
\caption{Comparación de características entre los instrumentos actuales para baterías en el mercado}
\begin{tabular}{|L{2cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|}\cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textbf{Cadex C7600~\cite{Cadexcompany}} & \textbf{Cadex C8000~\cite{Company}} & \textbf{NI PXI-4130~\cite{NationalInstruments2000}} &                    \textbf{Tektronix 2380~\cite{KEITHLEYaTektronixCompany}} & \textbf{Maynuo M9712C~\cite{MaynuoElectronic}}\\\hline  
\multicolumn{1}{|L{2.5cm}|}{Battery voltage range} & 1.2V - 36V & 1.2V - 36V & 0 - 20V & 0 - 500V & 0.1V - 150V \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|L{2.5cm}|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Discharge method}} &\multirow{4}{*}{Constant current} & \multirow{2}{*}{Constant current} & \multirow{2}{*}{Constant current} & Constant current & Constant current \\  &  & &  & Constant voltage & Constant voltage \\ &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Constant power} & \multirow{2}{*}{Constant voltage} & Constant resistance & Constant          resistance \\ &  &  &  & Constant power & Constant power \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|L{2.5cm}|}{Range of discharge current} & 100mA - 6A & 30mA - 10A & 2mA - 20mA & 0 - 15A & 0 - 6A \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|L{2.5cm}|}{Resolution} & 25 mA & 1mA & 100nA & 1 mA & 0.01 mA \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|L{2.5cm}|}{Exactitud} & 0.25\% FS & 0.25\% FS & 0.03\% FS & (0.05\% FR + 0.05\% FS) & 0.015\%FR + 0.05\%FS \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|L{2.5cm}|}{Operating Temperature} & 5\degree C - 35\degree C & 5\degree C - 35\degree C & 0\degree C - 55\degree C & 0\degree C - 40\degree C & 0\degree C - 40\degree C \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|L{2.5cm}|}{Display} & 2x40-character LCD & 5.7'' (145mm) QVGA 320x240 graphics with backlight & There isn’t available information & Monitor Output BNC & High-luminance VFD screen with two line \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|L{2.5cm}|}{Data ports} & RS-232 or USB interfaces to PC & Ethernet 10/100 MB for connection to PC & There isn’t available information & USB, RS-232, GPIB & USB, RS232, RS485 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'd appreciate any help and any suggestion to improve my table. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You shouldn't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` inside of a floating environment such as `table`. Use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` and remove the `\end{center}` part, this should center the caption as well, normally, but your table is just too wide, it leaks into the right margin

Comment: @Jeancarlo - Did you use Excel2LaTex to produce the table or did you write it from scratch yourself?

Comment: As well as the units should be typeset with the  `\SI` macro from the `siunitx` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well then I was so wrong because I've been using \begin{center}...\end{center} for almost all my figures and tables. I didn't know about that floating enviroment, I'll look into that for sure. Thank you ! By the way, how it would be the right way to use begin,end center? P.s: Thanks for SI package tip

Comment: @nikjohn I wrote it from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

**Edit:**
column type are changed from `raggedright` to `centering`, corrected wrong use of `adjustwidth` environment from package `changepage`. It is now loaded with option `strict` and adopted to use in the two side documents.

In your table I first remove all surplus `\multicolumn{1}{...}{....}`, than for `\multirow` use option `=` which preserve column formatting in multi row cells, reduce `\tabcolsep` to half of default value and for table use `tabularx` environment. Changes are in column type definitions too. Now `C` is accommodated to `tabularx` column type.

Instead of `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` is better to use `\centering`, which doesn't add vertical space around table.

In caption I remove option `center` (in package`center` it not exist) and for font size  select `\small`. Also I reduce distance between caption and table with `skip=1ex`. For units is used package `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,skip=1ex]{caption}% <-- changed

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage[notlot,notlof,nottoc,notindex]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}

\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[range-phrase = \,--\,]{siunitx}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-2.5cm}
    \centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\footnotesize
    \caption{Comparación de características entre los instrumentos actuales para baterías en el mercado}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| L{2cm} |
            >{\hsize=0.9\hsize}C |       
                        *{3}{C |}
            >{\hsize=1.1\hsize}C |
                             }
    \cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    &   \textbf{Cadex C7600~\cite{Cadexcompany}} 
        &   \textbf{Cadex C8000~\cite{Company}} 
            &   \textbf{NI PXI-4130~\cite{NationalInstruments2000}} 
                &   \textbf{Tektronix 2380~\cite{KEITHLEYaTektronixCompany}} 
                    &   \textbf{Maynuo M9712C~\cite{MaynuoElectronic}}              \\
    \hline
Battery voltage range   
    & \SIrange{1.2}{36}{V} & \SIrange{1.2}{36}{V} & \SIrange{0}{20}{V} 
        & \SIrange{0}{500}{V} & \SIrange{0.1}{150}{V} \\
    \hline
\multirow{4}{=}{Discharge method}
    &   \multirow{4}{=}{Constant current} 
        &   \multirow{2}{=}{Constant current} 
            &   \multirow{2}{=}{Constant current} 
                &   Constant current 
                    &   Constant current            \\  
    &   &   &   &   Constant voltage 
                    &   Constant voltage            \\ 
    &   &   \multirow{2}{*}{Constant power} 
            &   \multirow{2}{*}{Constant voltage} 
                    &   Constant resistance 
                        &   Constant resistance     \\ 
    &   &   &   &   Constant power 
                        & Constant power            \\
    \hline
Range of discharge current
    & \SIrange{0.1}{6}{A} & \SIrange{0.03}{10}{A} 
        & \SIrange{2}{20}{mA} & \SIrange{0}{15}{A} & \SIrange{0}{6}{A}  \\
    \hline
Resolution       
    & \SI{25}{mA} & \SI{1}{mA} & \SI{100}{nA} & \SI{1}{mA} & \SI{0.01}{mA} \\
    \hline
Exactitud        
    & \SI{0.25}{\%} FS & \SI{0.25}{\%} FS & \SI{0.03}{\%} FS 
        & (\SI{0.05}{\%} FR + \SI{0.05}{\%} FS) & \SI{0.015}{\%} FR + \SI{0.05}{\%} FS \\
    \hline
Operating Temperature
    & \SIrange{5}{35}{\degreeCelsius} & \SIrange{5}{35}{\degreeCelsius} 
        & \SIrange{0}{55}{\degreeCelsius} & \SIrange{0}{40}{\degreeCelsius} 
            & \SIrange{0}{40}{\degreeCelsius}\\
    \hline
Display  & 2x40-character LCD & \SI{5.7}{''} (145mm) QVGA 320x240 graphics with backlight & There isn’t available information & Monitor Output BNC & High-luminance VFD screen with two line \\
    \hline
Data ports  & RS-232 or USB interfaces to PC & Ethernet 10/100 MB for connection to PC & There isn’t available information & USB, RS-232, GPIB & USB, RS232, RS485 \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The problem with centering in your MWE probably arise from used definition of column type `C` and since the last column require slightly wider column width as is defined. Because you not use `english` babel, LaTeX doesn't know how to hyphenate English word, so it make spurious centering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It looks way cleaner than my code. However, I'm not able to compile because it throws me this error: `! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> C:/Jeancarlo/test/test.tex`

I'm using TeXworks' software. Also I tried compiling in sharelatex but didn't work. Which software do u use to compile tex files?

Comment: I use recent MikTeX 64-bit installation with recent package repository  on my PC and for editor use WinEdt. I test proposed solution and discover, that the code is not the last version and it contain error in columns definition: instead of `*{3}{>{C |}` had to be `*{3}{C |}`. Sorry for all inconvenience. Now the code is corrected and tested!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you set both arguments of `\adjustwidth` to `-2.5cm`, not just the first one. This will automatically give you a centered caption. For the two-row and four-row material in some of the cells, I suggest you use `tabular` environments rather than `\multirow` directives. Indeed, the code shown below doesn't use any `\multirow` instructions at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url, graphicx}

\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

%%\usepackage{multirow} % no longer needed
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{parskip} %
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1em} % not a good idea to make this a rigid length!
\parskip=1em \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5} % don't change "\baselinestretch" directly

\usepackage[notlot,notlof,nottoc,notindex]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\usepackage{changepage} % for "\adjustwidth" macro
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\hyphenation{dis-charge volt-age method infor-mation}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5cm}{-2.5cm}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2.5pt}
\captionsetup{size=small}
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Comparación de características entre los 
instrumentos actuales para baterías en el mercado}
\begin{tabular}{| L{2.25cm} | *{5}{C{3cm}|}}
\cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} 
& \textbf{Cadex C7600~\cite{Cadexcompany}} 
& \textbf{Cadex C8000~\cite{Company}} 
& \textbf{NI PXI-4130~\cite{NationalInstruments2000}} 
& \textbf{Tektronix 2380~\cite{KEITHLEYaTektronixCompany}} 
& \textbf{Maynuo M9712C~\cite{MaynuoElectronic}}\\
\hline
Battery voltage range & \SI{1.2}{\volt}--\SI{36}{\volt} 
& \SI{1.2}{\volt}--\SI{36}{\volt} & 0--\SI{20}{\volt} 
& 0--\SI{500}{\volt} & \SI{0.1}{\volt}--\SI{150}{\volt} \\
\hline
Discharge method & Constant current & 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Constant current \\ \\ Constant power 
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Constant current \\ \\ Constant voltage
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Constant current \\ Constant voltage \\ Constant resistance \\ Constant power 
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Constant current \\ Constant voltage \\ Constant resistance \\ Constant power
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
Range of discharge current & 100mA--6A & 30mA--10A & 2mA--20mA & 0--15A & 0--6A \\
\hline
Resolution & 25mA & 1mA & 100nA & 1mA & 0.01mA \\
\hline
Exactitud & 0.25\% FS & 0.25\% FS & 0.03\% FS & (0.05\% FR + 0.05\% FS) & 0.015\%FR + 0.05\%FS \\
\hline
Operating Temperature & \SI{5}{\celsius}--\SI{35}{\celsius} 
& \SI{5}{\celsius}--\SI{35}{\celsius} & \SI{0}{\celsius}--\SI{55}{\celsius} 
& \SI{0}{\celsius}--\SI{40}{\celsius} & \SI{0}{\celsius}--\SI{40}{\celsius} \\
\hline
Display & 2$\times$40-character LCD & 5.7'' (145mm) QVGA 320$\times$240 graphics with backlight & No information available & Monitor Output BNC & High-luminance VFD screen with two line \\
\hline
Data ports & RS-232 or USB interfaces to PC & Ethernet 10/100 MB for connection to PC & No information available & USB, RS-232, GPIB & USB, RS232, RS485 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some improvements, with `siunitx`, `makecell`, `stackengine` and ordinary cells. `Makecell` is designed to allow for line breaks inside cells. A lighter code: no `multirow`, no nested `tabular`. Playing with `tabcolsep`, I only add 1.5cm on each side.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper, spanish]{report}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=3cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{url, graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}%[center]

\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{gensymb}    
\usepackage{enumitem}   

\raggedbottom       

\usepackage{helvet}                 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}       

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}               
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}    

\usepackage[notlot,notlof,nottoc,notindex]{tocbibind}   
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}

\usepackage{array}      
\usepackage{booktabs}       
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{siunitx, makecell}
\sisetup{range-phrase=–, abbreviations=true, range-units=single, detect-all}
\DeclareSIUnit{\deg}{\degreeCelsius}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{-1.5cm}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setstackgap{L}{2.6ex}
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Comparación de características entre los instrumentos actuales para baterías en el mercado}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{5}{c|}}%
\cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textbf{Cadex C7600~\cite{Cadexcompany}} & \textbf{Cadex C8000~\cite{Company}} %
& \textbf{NI PXI-4130~\cite{NationalInstruments2000}} &      \textbf{Tektronix 2380~\cite{KEITHLEYaTektronixCompany}}%
& \textbf{Maynuo M9712C~\cite{MaynuoElectronic}}\\%
\hline
\makecell[l]{Battery\\[-0.8ex] voltage range} & \SIrange{1.2}{36}{V} & \SIrange{1.2}{36}{V} & \SIrange{0}{20}{V} & \SIrange{0}{500}{V} & \SIrange{0.1}{150}{V} \\%
\hline
Discharge method & Constant current & \makecell{Constant current \\[1ex] \\ Constant power} & \makecell{Constant current \\[1ex] \\ Constant voltage} & \makecell{Constant current \\[-0.5ex] Constant voltage \\[1ex] Constant resistance \\[-0.5ex] Constant power} & \makecell{Constant current \\[-0.5ex] Constant voltage \\[1ex] Constant resistance \\[-0.5ex]Constant power} \\
\hline
\makecell[l]{Range of \\[-0.8ex] discharge current} & \SI{100}{mA}\textendash\SI{6}{A} & \SI{30}{mA}– \SI{10}{A} & \SIrange{2}{20}{mA} & \SIrange{0}{15}{A} & \SIrange{0}{6}{A} \\%
\hline
Resolution & \SI{25}{mA} & \SI{1}{mA} & \SI{100}{nA} & \SI{1}{mA} & \SI{0.01}{mA} \\%
\hline
Exactitude & 0.25\% FS & 0.25\% FS & 0.03\% FS & \Centerstack{(0.05\% FR \\+ 0.05\% FS)} & \Centerstack{0.015\% FR\\ + 0.05\% FS} \\%
\hline
\makecell[l]{Operating\\[-0.8ex] Temperature} & \SIrange{5}{35}{\deg}& \SIrange{5}{35}{\deg} & \SIrange{0}{55}{\deg} & \SIrange{0}{40}{\deg} & \SIrange{0}{40}{\deg} \\%
\hline
Display & \Centerstack{2\,x\,40-character\\ LCD} & \Centerstack{5.7'' (145mm) QVGA \\320\,x\,240 graphics\\ with backlight} & \Centerstack{No available\\ information} & Monitor Output BNC & \Centerstack{High-luminance\\ VFD screen\\ with two lines} \\%
\hline
Data ports & \Centerstack{RS-232 or USB\\ interfaces to PC} & \Centerstack{Ethernet 10/100 MB\\ for connection to PC} & \Centerstack{No available\\ information} & USB, RS-232, GPIB & USB, RS232, RS485 \\%
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]